# Sending a POST to Spring endpoint giving status 400

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, go, post

It appears that there is an issue passing the **playerId** parameter from the frontend to the backend in a React app. The createGame function in the Spring controller is set up to receive a playerId parameter, but the value is not being properly passed from the frontend using **Axios**. It has been attempted to use a **Long and a String** for the playerId, but the issue persists.
Still getting status 400 !

[Spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEDPj.png)

[React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Miww.png)

1. Store it as a String parameter.
2. I used @PathVariable.
3. I tried to direct write the parameter in Postman.
4. I tried change endpoint.
5. Another endpoint (/login) which i'm not showing works good so no problem with proxy.

Comment: Async? there appears to be one program passing to another, one is Async so maybe the other needs to be asynchronous. Have you tried printing the player I'd and the info passed in each call request to verify the data is actually there at each stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shared React screenshot - it looks like you send a JSON body.

However, in Spring Controller - @RequestParam is used.

It looks like you either need to change React part to call URL like '/api/games/{playerId}' (so playerId would be passed as part of URL) or update Spring Controller to accept @RequestBody (and create a class with field 'playerId') - so whole object could be passed as request body.

As currently React sends a body - but Spring is looking for a URL query param. Both parts need to do same thing - whatever it will be.

Spring changes would look like:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> createGame(@RequestBody PlayerRequest playerRequest) {
    Long playerId = playerRequest.getPlayerId();
    // other code goes here
}

public class PlayerRequest {
    private Long playerId;

    public Long getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(Long playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806841) is correct but I overwrite the code like this:

```
@PostMapping("/games")
public ResponseEntity<String> createGame(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestParams) {
    try {
        Long playerId = Long.parseLong(requestParams.get("playerId").toString());
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String gameCreated = now.format(formatter);
        Player player = playerRepository.findById(playerId).orElse(null);
        if (player == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        Game game = new Game(gameCreated);
        gameRepository.save(game);
        GamePlayer gamePlayer = new GamePlayer(game, player);
        gamePlayerRepository.save(gamePlayer);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Game created successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failed to create game.");
    }
}
```

And the React will be send like this:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`/api/games?playerId=${parseInt(storedPlayerId)}`);
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      // handle the error
    }
};
```